# How to potty train a toddler?

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My son is 2 1/2 years old. He has been going potty on the potty off and on since he was 18 months. He was interested due to having cousins just a little older than him. Unfortunately the problem we are running into is he won’t tell me when he has to go.

Most people say he is too young to know that he has to go, but he knows well enough to run out of the room or into a different room when he has to go. Even when I ask him he will say no then go in the other room and purposely pee or poo. If I take him to the potty he will fight and not want to sit on it but when he finally sits he goes potty. We’ve tried having potty parties and sticker charts. Sometimes He won’t even tell us when he potty’s he will just change his undies and keep going with playing.

How can we potty train our toddler?

Comment: Sounds like to me he's somehow embarrassed about it, if he's concealing himself or the *criminal evidence*.

Answer (score 0):

2 1/2 too young to potty train?  Don't you believe that for a second.  By his actions he clearly knows what he's doing and has control over this process.  Children this young don't like to put a pause on life for potty training.  You have to property motivate them to want to do it in the right place.

What we've done with all of our children is get a pack of suckers/favorite candy/etc. which we give out when they go on the potty.  Initially, they get rewarded for anything done in the right place, then we start to pull back once they get accustomed to the process, typically rewarding only if they tell us they need to go, or have success in something you've previously had lots of accidents over.  In my experience, they eventually forget about the rewards and just do it after awhile.

Good luck, it's tough at first, you just have to stick with it!  You can't switch back and forth either, every day, every hour he's awake needs to be in underwear.  For naptime/bedtime I would stick with diapers/pull-ups as children develop that ability slower than during waking hours.

Answer (score 0):

Someone (somewhere) came up with the idea of "targets" for the toilet bowl. They are relatively inexpensive, made of (tissue) paper - I think - which makes them flushable. It turns toilet training into a game of sorts. And just might get your little one interested in going to the "right spot at the right time".
[random product link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MGVR6I)